# StackOverflow error when calling DataContext.SubmitChanges()

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, stack-overflow

In a hybrid asp.net web application, framework 4.5.1, using LINQ to SQL (not Entity Framework) I'm getting the exception

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll"

on any call to `DataContext.SubmitChanges()`.

Every call to SubmitChanges() causes the error, it does not matter what specific entity is being altered.  The error is thrown immediately (unlike most StackOverflow exceptions, which normally take a few seconds to occur while the errant code overflows the stack).

The asp.net web application is running on my local host in IIS express using Visual Studio 2013.  The database is SQL Server 2005.

My question is, how does one debug a StackOverflow exception in this environment?  Right now the above error message is all I get.

> 1. The Event Viewer notes that the browser crashed (it happens in both IE 11 and Chrome) but nothing about the LINQ to SQL exception.
> 2. The SQL Server process monitor does not register any database call.
> 3. I have a log hooked up to my DataContext but it records nothing.

It appears the stack overflow is happening inside `System.Data.dll` before any database call occurs and before anything can be logged.

This suddenly started happening several hours ago, after a windows update ran and the machine rebooted.  That might be a coincidence.

Something else extremely odd: we have four developers in our shop, all using Visual Studio 2013.  Two of us suddenly began having this problem, and two of us never had it.  We're all running identical code and hitting the same database.  The two of us having the problem rebooted, and the problem disappeared on one machine, but is still occurring on my machine.

In addition to rebooting, I've deleted the project from machine and pulled it down from source control so that it is identical to what my 3 co-workers have, deleted all temporary internet files on my machine, and deleted all of my AppData\Local\temp files for my login.

Is there any way to debug this issue?

Clip of call stack when exception occurs (the calls to VisitExpression and etc repeat many dozens of times until it ends).

[image]

Comment: Is it specific to one context class, or more?

Comment: @GertArnold, no, not specific to any context class.  Any call to SubmitChanges() throws the exception.  Does not matter what database entity is being altered.

Comment: What if you connect to the database in Linqpad (which uses LINQ to SQL under the hood)?

Comment: Can you attach the debugger and look at the Call Stack window when the SO happens?

Comment: @usr: yes, I'm running it in Visual Studio so I don't need to attach a debugger, I added picture of the call stack when the exception occurs.

Comment: This is a L2S bug. Could be data dependent. It's hard to debug this because there is no user-provided query to look at. Maybe the schema has a weird configuration? Something cyclical? Post excerpts of the DBML. We need to find a workaround.

Comment: @usr, what does "L2S bug" mean?

Comment: @usr, the dbml is an unholy mess, legacy stuff, way too much to post here.  But I don't think the answer lies in the dbml.  Every call to DataContext.SubmitChanges() fails, it does not matter which entity is being updated.  Also, my 3 coworkers can save the same entities on their machines using the identical code.  This is something that suddenly started occurring on my machine.

Comment: Maybe a different framework version? Windows update patch für .NET? Or, the solution is not entirely identical. Reset the solution folder using source control. *Something* is different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103622/discussion-between-tom-regan-and-usr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unsatisfying "answer" in this case was to delete the *.dbml file and re-create it.  That fixed the stack overflow error.

My comment in reply to @GertArnold above was not accurate.  Only one DataContext was throwing the stack overflow exception.  It was doing it for every entity in the DataContext, but other DataContexts in the application were working properly.

This particular *.dbml file has been growing over the years to gargantuan size. While re-creating I was careful to only add database objects that are being referenced, which resulted in a much smaller *.dbml file, which might itself have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Tom for the info!

Just in case other people may hit the same problem, here is extra info from my case. I have got a very similar issue after my PC got a batch of Windows updates yesterday, the updates including windows10 OS, VS2013/VS2015 and etc. I primarily use VS2013, some differences with Tom's case are,

1. it only pops up when update one entity, other entities in the same DataContext work fine
2. only affects my ASP.NET Web API project, console applications are fine, even all app projects ref to the same unitofwork data layer project (in where the dbml file sits)
3. replacing the dbml file didn't work for me, I finally solved it by opening the solution in VS2015 >> debugging >> closing VS2015 >> opening the solution in VS2013, the problem just disappeared